# How to check if text.contains() contains multiple values

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text edit controller and I would like to check mutliple characters in the same contains ()

```
_changeUsernameController.text.contains("a" "b") // what I want

_changeUsernameController.text.contains("a") ||
_changeUsernameController.text.contains("b") // what I have to do
```

I don't want to write 50 lines so how can I write all in one line like the 'what I want' line
Thanks

Comment: You can use Regex maybe?

Comment: Can you write the code please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [any](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/any.html) method to write less code for the very same effect:

```
final subStrings = <String>["a", "b" /* ... */ ];
var result = subStrings.any(_changeUsernameController.text.contains);
```

Or if you prefer it even shorter:

```
var result = ["a", "b"].any(_changeUsernameController.text.contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `RegExp`, try this:

```
var reg = RegExp(r'(?:a)|(?:b)');
_changeUsernameController.text.contains(reg);
```

**example:**

```
var test1 = 'acc';
var test2 = 'cc';
var test3 = 'ccb';
print(test1.contains(reg)); //true
print(test2.contains(reg)); //false
print(test3.contains(reg)); //true
```

Comment: It's not working with 
String oui = 'Tamara'; for exemple

Comment: I update my answer, remove `^` from regex. @Boatti

Comment: Yes it was that thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

Create a function like this:

```
bool containsAny(String text, List<String> substrings) {
  // returns true if any substring of the [substrings] list is contained in the [text]
  for (var substring in substrings) {
    if (text.contains(substring)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
final text = 'Flutter';
final result = containsAny(text, ['c', 'd', 'e']); // true
final result2 = containsAny(text, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // false
```

Comment: Thanks but I used @nvoigt solution